# Magento 1.9.1 Color Swatch

Tags: magento-1.9, color-swatches

For Magento 1.9.1 Color Swatches, I wonder if it support 
**Multiple Swatches that both lead to an image change?**

For example, my product is a "Pen with a rubber attached", can i make 2 color swatch one for the pen color and the second swatch for the rubber color.
And user can see the correct color combination after the 2 swatches are selected?

many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can select multiple attributes to be used as a swatch, when all options are selected the image from the resulting simple will be shown.

To select multiple swatches goto:
System=>Configuration => Configurable Swatches => 'Product Attributes to Show as Swatches in Product Detail' and select the attributes you want to use as a swatch.

[image: Configure attributes to use as swatch]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, still my concern is about the **Image Swap** <br> When I have two swatches, e.g. One is pen-color and another is pen-logo, what will be the image shown after the selection? That will be based on the Color attribute, or the Shoe-logo attribute or can swap to an image that has specify that particular color and shoe-logo?

Comment: When all selections are made the image from the simple product is used, this is the final color combination so should give you the correct image.