# Magento 1 add a color swatch link on one step checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add a color swatch option for config product on one step checkout page, can someone guide me on how can I do this?

Is short, I want to give user option to change color on one step checkout page.

The color swatcher option are already available on product details page, I need it on one step checkout page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 1.9.1 Color Swatch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54740/magento-1-9-1-color-swatch)

Answer (score 0):

Since, I cannot post comment so I prefer to share the link through answer here.

Check out the image [image: Magento 1.9.1 Color Swatch Problem Solution]

Or, better go with the solution here:

[Magento 1.9.1 Color Swatch](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54740/magento-1-9-1-color-swatch)